# Infragistics UltraGrid : Unable to enter edit mode for focused column

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, infragistics, edit, ultrawingrid

**Info:**

I am working with a C#.NET 3.5 winforms application and using Infragistics ultrgrid 8.2 in it. The grid has 5 columns, of which first three are readonly and 4th and 5th are valuelisted dropdowns. The 4th column is called "From".

**What do I want to achieve:**

When form launches, I want to set focus to first row cell for "From" column and also have it in edit mode.

**What have I coded :**

I have written following function

---

private void SetFocus()

```
    {
        _grid.Focus();
        _grid.ActiveCell = _grid.Rows[0].Cells["From"];
        _grid.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode);
        _grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["From"].Editor.Focus();
    }
```

---

Which when called through form's paint event, works fine. But it is irritating to see the control get focus on each paint. Calling this on load, gets the focus right; but does not set the control in edit mode.

Thanks already

Jyotsna

Comment: What other events are you trying it in?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I did a little Googling and maybe,

```
_grid.Rows[0].Cells["From"].Activate();
```

instead of calling

```
_grid.ActiveCell = _grid.Rows[0].Cells["From"];
```

Can't be sure if it will make a difference but give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the post .. but it did not work :( .... I am really not sure why it works on paint but not on other events

Comment: Infragistics can do anything, but figuring it out is not intuitive... not even a little.

Answer (score 0):

Solved here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195640/ultrawingrid-enter-edit-mode-issue)

```
var cell = ... // Get the cell

if (cell != null)
{
     BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
     {
          cell.Activate();
          bugGrid.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode);
     }));
}
```