# UltraWinGrid enter edit mode issue

Tags: vb.net, focus, row, ultrawingrid

I have an UltraWinGrid and I want to give the focus to a specific cell and make it enter edit mode programmatically (*no click*). So I did this :

```
If myUltraWinGrid.ActiveRow IsNot Nothing Then
myUltraWinGrid.ActiveCell = myUltraWinGrid.ActiveRow.Cells("foo")
myUltraWinGrid.PerformAction(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode)
Else
myUltraWinGrid.ActiveCell = myUltraWinGrid.Rows(0).Cells("foo")
myUltraWinGrid.PerformAction(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode)
EndIf
```

Which should work but it only gives focus to the row (no edit mode).

```
fooColumn   
   |
  \_/
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but calling it with `BeginInvoke` solved the issue.

```
BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AdressOf SetFocusToRow))

Private sub SetFocusToRow()
{
  myUltraWinGrid.ActiveCell = myUltraWinGrid.ActiveRow.Cells("foo")
  myUltraWinGrid.PerformAction(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the code to enter edit mode wasn't being called from the main UI thread?

Comment: @JeffBridgman Maybe. I'm not good with threading. But it makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Because it's executed by another thread by some reason

myUltraWinGrid.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(()=> myUltraWinGrid.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode)));

Comment: This is a comment to the answer by phadaphunk rather than an answer itself.